# Created an audit script for AD in Powershell, but I need to have the security group appear per each user in a column. Is this possible?

Tags: powershell

i am new-ish to Powershell and I am completely stumped here

the goal is to have a script that runs nightly that i will be loading to a table in SQL for a general audit report that managers can access. the script that i have so far is this:

```
Get-ADgroup -Filter 'Name -like "Security Group -*"' -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=ADAccess,DC=local" 
-Properties members | select name, @{n=’Members’; e= { ( $_.members | % { 

(Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} 
| Sort-Object -Property Name | Export-csv -path C:\AuditScript\Audit.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

this yields a result like this:

```
name                            Members
security group - 1              user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4
security group - 2              user 4, user 5, user 9
```

this is great for doing quick manual audits, but ideally this would be loaded to a table in SQL and queried against

ideally the report would look like this:

```
name                        Members
security group - 1          user 1
security group - 1          user 2
security group - 1          user 3
security group - 1          user 4
security group - 2          user 4
security group - 2          user 5
security group - 2          user 9
```

is this possible? i have been grinding at this for a couple days now and am pretty frustrated

thank you for any and all help,

Answer (score 0):

To do that, simply loop over the groups the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet returns.
I would also add a column 'MemberType' because members can be users, groups or computers

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'Security Group -*'" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=ADAccess,DC=local" -Properties Members | 
ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_.Name
    foreach ($member in $_.Members) {
        $member | Get-ADObject | 
                  Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group}},
                                @{Name = 'Member'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                                @{Name = 'MemberType'; Expression = {$_.objectClass}}
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property Group, Member | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\AuditScript\Audit.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also use the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet instead of `Get-ADObject`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'Security Group -*'" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=ADAccess,DC=local" | 
ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    $group | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group.Name}},
                                               @{Name = 'Member'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                                               @{Name = 'MemberType'; Expression = {$_.objectClass}}
} | Sort-Object -Property Group, Member | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\AuditScript\Audit.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```